# Easy question about vector spaces

Tags: vector-spaces

Suppose $F$ is a (added later: finite-dimensional) vector space over $K$ and $K'$ is a subfield of $K$. If $\dim_K F = \dim_{K'} F$, then how does one prove that $K=K'$? Somehow I can't quite show that $K \subseteq K'$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{R}$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and the dimensions are the same.

But $\dim_{K'} F = (\dim_K F)(\dim_{K'} K)$, so if $\dim_K F$ is finite then $\dim_{K'} K = 1$.

Comment: Good point. In fact I had a finite-dimensional vector space in mind (I added it to the question).

Comment: Yeah I figured that's what you meant